# Cake PHP login username not checking uppercase and lower case

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have created a login function. At the moment when correct login details are entered it logs in the employee and if inaccurate details are entered shows error message. Issue is if a employee enters a correct username but wrong case it still logs in the employee. For example, if there is a employee in the database with username "admin", if I enter username as "ADMIN" or "Admin" with correct password in login, it will still log in the employee. My code is as follows:

employeesController:

```
<?php
class EmployeesController extends AppController {
//some code here

public function login()
    {
        $username=$this->request->data['username'];
        App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
        $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
        $password = $passwordHasher->hash($this->request->data['password']);
        $msg = $this->Employee->authenticateUser($username,$password);
        if($msg)
        {
            foreach ($msg as $userdetails)
            {
                $usertype=$userdetails['Employee']['access_level'];//either admin or staff


            }
            //set session variables to limit authority
            $this->Session->write(array('User' => array(
                'usertype' => $usertype


            )));

            $this->render("../Pages/index1"); 
            $this->layout = '../Pages/index1';

        }
        else{
            $this->set('error',$username);
            $this->render("../Pages/home"); //login page is the home page
            $this->layout = '../Pages/home';

        }



    }
}
```

home.ctp:

```
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
var y=document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please Enter Username")
  return false;
  }
  if (y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Please Enter Password")
  return false;
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<div class="users form">
<br>
<br>
<br>

<form name="myForm" action="Employees/login" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
<?php

    if (isset($error)) {


    echo "<p style='color:red;font-size: 20px''>Username or Password is invalid. Please try again.</p>";


        }?>
        <p>Enter Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" style="height: 25px;width: 160px;"/></p>
        <br><br>
        <p>Enter Password:
        <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="password" style="height: 25px;width: 160px;"/></p>
        <br>
<input type="submit" style="height:35px;width:100px;font-size: 18px; align:center;" value="Sign in">

   </form>
</div>
```

Can someone please help? I want only the exact username to be able to log in.

Answer (score 3):

regardless the framework you are using this problem depends on th charset of your DB.
Problably you are using an *_ci charset (case insensitive).
Also *_cs (case sensitive) charset exists if you really need it.

Comment: By the way I'm using mySQL with a wamp server. And the DB charset I'm using is utf8_general_ci. Is that an issue?

Comment: Yes ci means case insensitive.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. Anyway, unless you have a client that specifically asked for it I do not see any problem having a CI username, event Google and Facebook have it.